# Can the Option Set file for Delphi 10 be set programmatically using the OTAPI?

Tags: delphi, ide, toolsapi, otapi

Is it possible to automate setting the *Option Set* file reference programmatically when creating a new Delphi project using the `IOTAProjectOptions` respectively `IOTAProjectOptionsConfigurations` interface<sup>1</sup>?

Or can I do that using any of the other [OTAPI IDE services](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Obtaining_Tools_API_Services)<sup>2</sup>?

I'm currently using the RAD Studio Delphi 10 Seattle IDE. Though, if newer OTAPI versions would support that feature, I'd still like to know about that.

I couldn't find any appropriate property or function, that seems to do that action in my current `ToolsAPI.pas`.

I want to achieve the same as choosing [*`Apply Option Set -> Reference`*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Project_Manager#Build_Configurations_Context_Menu) at the root project configurations root node in the IDE's project manager view:

[image]

Hypothetically I'm looking for some functionality like

```
procedure IOTAProjectOptionsConfigurations.BaseConfiguration.ApplyOptionSetReference
   (const optSetFilePath : string);
```

---

#### A bit more background:

I'm currently developing legacy project wizards for our company wide Delphi project settings. I already have a working `IOTAProjectCreator` implementation that also manipulates the `.dproj` MSBuild XML file after it was generated and saved by the IDE. I'm just adding some conditional `Import` elements there.

Now we also want to use a *Options Set file* that is stored at a central repository. I know and studied the differences done in the `.dproj` XML, after that action was applied using the GUI, but there's a non negligible amount of logic going on (regarding dependencies and such), and I'm refraining to (re-)implement that logic via plain XML file manipulations. Not to mention that the necessary logic is prone to be changed with future versions of the IDE.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>I'm trying to use that in the context of a `IOTAProjectCreator` implementation, with the definition of the `procedure SetInitialProjectOptions(NewProject : IOTAProject);` function.</sub>

<sup>2)</sup><sub>It's a shame that these features are documented so poorly.</sub>

Comment: I edited the title and tags. There's no such thing as XE10 and you aren't using XE.

Comment: @David THX. I'm using RAD Studio Seattle actually. I don't know exactly what the compiler version is.

Comment: The compiler version is displayed in the caption of the IDE. Mine says something like `Project68 - RAD Studio 10 Seattle - Project68.dpr`. The About box also tells you the version.

Comment: @Rudy THX. I don't have it at hand. I know that there are certain OTA interface versions for certain compiler / IDE versions. I didn't find anything for mine though.

Comment: The OTAPI is the only way to manipulate the IDE with code.The older versions are *extended* by the newer ones. So a new version may have more functionality, but old functionality is not removed. So everything you see in the ToolsAPI sources for Seattle is available for Seattle too.

Comment: @Rudy /OT Do you know if any of the Embarcadero devs hang around here? I know of Remy and David as reputable tag contributors (no Embarcadero employees though). I also have some contacts via FB, but getting informal contact to Embarcadero officials beyond getting spammed with their marketing stuff, seems to be hard to impossible.

Comment: @David ^^^^^ I don't want to write the whole thing again. Not to mention I mentioned you ;-)